# sql: reverse function of Char()

Tags: mysql, sql, function

in SQL, char() converts an integer to a character (e.g., char(101) returns 'e'). What's the reverse function of char() (e.g., convert 'e' to 101)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`ORD()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_ord) or [`ASCII()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_ascii), though they're not strictly a reverse since they will only handle the first character of the string passed in whereas [`CHAR()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_char) can build a string from a list of digits.

As per [Michael Buen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10344688/8331) it's worth noting that `ORD()` is MySql-only, whereas `ASCII()` is more widely supported but doesn't handle multi-byte characters.

```
mysql> SELECT CHAR(104), ASCII('h'), ORD('h');
+-----------+------------+----------+
| CHAR(104) | ASCII('h') | ORD('h') |
+-----------+------------+----------+
| h         |        104 |      104 |
+-----------+------------+----------+
```

Answer (score 6):

I was about to upvote BluesRockAddict's answer, but he deleted his answer, but it's the best answer, ASCII works on many platforms, e.g. SQL Server, Oracle, Postgresql, and of course MySQL

```
SELECT ASCII('e')
```

ORD works on MySQL only

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/